# NSDate/NSDateFormatter - Storing only time, not date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've been looking around but I haven't seen anything that addresses this so I'm hoping someone can help clear this up for me. What I am trying to do is use an NSDate variable(in core data) to store a time, not date and time, but just time in the format HH:MM:SS;

After looking at the NSDateFormatter class reference and the sample code provided I was able to tweak it and think that my code should look something like the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *timeOfArrival = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeOfArrival setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[timeOfArrival setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[timeOfArrival setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];

NSString *etaStr = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"cumulativeTime"];
NSLog(@"%@", etaStr);
checkpoint.eta = [timeOfArrival dateFromString:etaStr];
```

Everything up until the last line where I try to create my NSDate object from my string works, but after that, checkpoint.eta is still nil.

etaStr correctly outputs my expected value, 00:14:00, for example, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I ended up not using NSDate/NSDateFormatter because I couldn't get it to work properly. My solution consisted of parsing my time string into a hours, minutes, and seconds. I eventually ended up converting everything to seconds, and storing them in that way.

Answer (score 19):

After setting the locale and the date format you should be able to convert from date to string and back. Because you just need the time, you can ignore the date part.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] 
                 initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *etaStr = @"00:14:00";
NSDate *generatedDate = [formatter dateFromString:etaStr];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:generatedDate]);
[formatter release];
```

Output

```
00:14:00
```

#### Swift version

Time to update this answer for swift:

```
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let etaString = "00:14:00"
let generatedDate = formatter.dateFromString(etaString)!
let generatedString = formatter.stringFromDate(generatedDate)
println(generatedString)
```

#### Swift 3 version

```
var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let etaString = "00:14:00"
let generatedDate = formatter.date(from: etaString)!
let generatedString = formatter.string(from: generatedDate)
print(generatedString)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mundi.  I down voted you, but would take it back if I could.  Leaving the date part out of etaStr threw me off a bit.  If you edit it to add a date, I will up vote you again.

Comment: actually, I can't..."You last voted on this answer 16 hours ago Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited" so I can't upvote again unless you edit and add a date to *etaStr...because you're not making it clear that a time can be pulled out of an NSDate where there is a date and time as the OP specified.

Comment: Made the code a bit clearer to see where the date is generated.

Comment: I also made mine more clear and to the OP's point of using [attributeDict objectForKey:@"cumulativeTime"] as a full 12/21/12 15:22:00 PM timestamp he's most likely getting from an XML based web service and storing it in core data.  It seems he's getting a full date/time, and only wants the time, so your code will work, it's just not showing the full @"12/21/12 00:14:00" timestamp he needs to cut in half...keep up the good work, and your sign of approval Mundi would really make my day...do you see the benefit of my answer too?? Upvote time, Mundnificent!

Answer (score 2):

After thinking this through a bit, and trying Mundi's answer, it looked like Mundi was creating a string from a string without creating an NSDate or converting to or from an NSDate.  I needed to store an NSDate as well, so here's how you can get what you want fairly easily:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *eventDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"cumulativeTime"]];
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss a"];
NSString *timeString = [timeFormat stringFromDate:eventDate];
NSLog(@"EventDate: %@",timeString);
```

Mundi's answer works, so someone should upvote his answer since I down voted too fast without taking into account that leaving off the date @"1/21/13 00:14:00" doesn't really matter in this case, but he should have put a date in front of it to make it clear that the date isn't output.  Someone's variable from a web service or some other object would have the date, then the @"HH:mm:ss a" would pull out the time only.  This also helps those who need the AM/PM on their date or time.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**
If you want to use time with today's date

```
let todate = Date()
        let formater = DateFormatter()
        formater.dateFormat = "yyyy:MM:dd"
       let date = formater.string(from: todate)
        print(date)
        let completeDate = date + ":9:00AM"
        print(completeDate)
        let anotherFormater = DateFormatter()
        anotherFormater.dateFormat = "EEEEE MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
       anotherFormater.date(from: completeDate)
```

if you want to add time in any date then:-

```
  let completeDate = "2019-02-15" + ":9:00AM"
            print(completeDate)
            let anotherFormater = DateFormatter()
            anotherFormater.dateFormat = "EEEEE MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
           anotherFormater.date(from: completeDate)
```