# How to properly sort an NSDictonary by key values that contain strings of time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm not understanding exactly why it's not sorting properly. I have an NSDictionary that contains key values of times in the day. When I try to sort it, it's not properly ordered.

```
events = @{@"12:00 PM" : @[@"1"],
           @"12:30 PM" : @[@"2"],
           @"1:00 PM" : @[@"3", @"4"],
           @"1:30 PM" : @[@"5", @"11"],
           @"2:00 PM" : @[@"6"],
           @"3:00 PM" : @[@"7"],
           @"3:30 PM" : @[@"8"],
           @"4:00 PM" : @[@"9"],
           @"4:30 PM" : @[@"10", @"11"],
           @"5:00 PM" : @[@"12", @"13", @"14"]};

eventTimes = [ [events allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

When I NSLog eventTimes, it produces the output:

> (
>       "1:00  PM",
>       "1:30  PM",
>       "12:00 PM",
>       "12:30 PM",
>       "2:00  PM",
>       "3:00  PM",
>       "3:30  PM",
>       "4:00  PM",
>       "4:30  PM",
>       "5:00  PM" )

How can I achieve this output?

> (
>       "12:00  PM",
>       "12:30  PM",
>       "1:00 PM",
>       "1:30 PM",
>       "2:00  PM",
>       "3:00  PM",
>       "3:30  PM",
>       "4:00  PM",
>       "4:30  PM",
>       "5:00  PM" )

UPDATE: I tried:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] ];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSString *etaStr = [eventTimes objectAtIndex:section];
NSDate *generatedDate = [formatter dateFromString:etaStr];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:generatedDate]);
```

However, I get nil.

Comment: You need to convert the times to a sortable format such as `1300` for `1 PM` and `1630` for `4:30 PM`.

Comment: I *think* that if you used `compare:` with the NSNumericSearch option that would work, without having to reformat the values.

Comment: @HotLicks That won't work because 12 PM would end up after 1 PM.

Comment: @rmaddy - Yeah, that's a separate problem from the simple 2:00/10:00 sort issue, I guess.

Comment: Of course, the other option is to write your own comparator.  It's fairly simple to do and avoids the need to reformat the key values.

Comment: @rmaddy, if I convert the time to military time for the key values of my NSDictionary, how would I use a NSDateFormatter to retrieve the military time key to a standard time key? I know I can use a bunch of if statements and set 13:00 to 1:00 but that is tedious and a lot of code

Comment: Writing custom comparator for time strings is not very practical as it would require to convert time anyway

Comment: Well, you'd read the date with a "h:mm a" format, and write with "HH:mm" format.  And be sure to set the formatter to UTC timezone.

Comment: @Andy - Not necessarily, and even if so it's not a big deal.

Comment: @Hot Licks, I'm not sure I understand :(

Comment: @Pangu - You don't understand what?  How to use an NSDateFormatter?  How to write a custom comparator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Keep time as number of seconds, timestamp or `NSDate`.
2. Use regular sort.
3. Use `NSDateFormatter` to produce time string in preferred format. Generally keep your application data in format that is friendly to your internal data organization and do formatting before you display it on screen.

Regarding `NSDateFormatter` questions and how to convert time string to `NSDate`, I played around in Playground and it seems that the key is to set `ShortStyle` format for time, setup `en_US` locale since you convert from 12h time and make sure you use `UTC` timezone to avoid any time offset because your time is absolute anyway.

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

// Input
var times = [
    "3:30 PM", "4:00 PM", "4:30 PM",
    "5:00 PM", "12:30 PM", "12:00 PM",
    "1:00 PM", "1:30 PM", "2:00 PM",
    "3:00 PM"
]

// Create array of NSDate objects
var dates = NSMutableArray()

println("Convert time string to NSDate")
println()

// Setup formatter for the US time style
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")

// Loop thru input data and convert time string to NSDate
for t in times {
    let date = formatter.dateFromString(t)

    dates.addObject(date!)

    println("t = \(t) converted as \(date)")
}

println()
println("Sort array of NSDate objects")
println()

// Sort dates
let sortedDates = dates.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([ NSSortDescriptor(key: "self", ascending: true) ])

// Print out sorted array of dates
for d in sortedDates {
    let date = d as NSDate
    let formattedString = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
    println("\(formattedString)")
}
```

Now all of that is in Swift but I am sure it's intuitive enough to write the same code in Objective-C.

The console output:

```
Convert time string to NSDate

t = 3:30 PM converted as Optional(2000-01-01 15:30:00 +0000)
t = 4:00 PM converted as Optional(2000-01-01 16:00:00 +0000)
t = 4:30 PM converted as Optional(2000-01-01 16:30:00 +0000)
t = 5:00 PM converted as Optional(2000-01-01 17:00:00 +0000)
t = 12:30 PM converted as Optional(2000-01-01 12:30:00 +0000)
t = 12:00 PM converted as Optional(2000-01-01 12:00:00 +0000)
t = 1:00 PM converted as Optional(2000-01-01 13:00:00 +0000)
t = 1:30 PM converted as Optional(2000-01-01 13:30:00 +0000)
t = 2:00 PM converted as Optional(2000-01-01 14:00:00 +0000)
t = 3:00 PM converted as Optional(2000-01-01 15:00:00 +0000)

Sort array of NSDate objects

12:00 PM
12:30 PM
1:00 PM
1:30 PM
2:00 PM
3:00 PM
3:30 PM
4:00 PM
4:30 PM
5:00 PM
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how to go about achieving this since the time is not "real" time. I know I can change the time to military time as key values for my NSDictionary, but how do I format each key to standard time?

Comment: The easiest is to use Unix timestamp. You can still convert it to `NSDate` For convenience if needed via `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970`. You can neglect the date itself and use only time component of it. Timestamp can be in range from 0 to 86400 which covers 0-24 hours.

Comment: Even if you get time input as is you can still use `NSDateFormatter.dateFromString`. If you get time in 12h US system just make sure you set proper locale. Once you convert time you'll be able to format and sort your time easily. Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString:

Comment: I apologize, I'm still fairly new to objective-c. Can you provide an example?

Comment: A related answer how to convert US time to NSDate http://stackoverflow.com/a/7154291/351305

Comment: Hi andy, thanks for the suggestion. I'm still facing some issue. Please see my UPDATE above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66304/discussion-between-pangu-and-andy).

Answer (score 1):

Your keys are strings, and you are doing a lexicographically comparison of the strings. In that comparison, 1:00 is less than 12:30 becacuse `:` is less than `2`.

If you want to sort by dates, you will first need to convert it to a type that can actually convey the time value in a conversion. This could be NSDate, or a simple integer representing an offset from midnight.

Answer (score 0):

A simple comparator can do

```
NSArray *sortedAllKeys = [[events allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateFormat =@"h:mm a";
        [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US.POSIX"] ];
    });
    return [[formatter dateFromString:obj1] compare:[formatter dateFromString:obj2]];
}];
```

[Technical Note QA1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) might be interesting for you.